# Plotly and Shiny: onclick switch tabs to created plot

Tags: shiny, plotly, shiny-reactivity, ggplotly

I created a simple plot that when the user clicks on a point it generates another plot on a second tab, `Page_2` -- is it possible to add some custom JS so that when the user clicks on the point they are automatically re-routed to the Page_2 tab?

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

# ui with two panes
# when you click on the outlier in the first plot
# you are routed to the second "point explorer" page
ui <- navbarPage("Plotly On Click Switch Pane",
                 tabPanel("Page_1",
                          mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot"),
                                    tableOutput("text"))),
                 tabPanel("Page_2",
                          mainPanel(plotlyOutput("ind_plot"))
                  ))


server <- function(input, output) {

  # plot on first page
   output$plot <- renderPlotly({
     ggplotly(source = "sub_iris",
       ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width)) +
         geom_boxplot()
     )
   })

   # create reactive for subset plot on second tab
   s <- reactive({ event_data("plotly_click", source = "sub_iris") })

   # plot text on first page (test)
   output$text <- renderTable(event_data("plotly_click", source = "sub_iris"))

   # this is the correct plot, but I want to re-route the user here when they click on a point
   output$ind_plot <- renderPlotly({
     iris_ind <- subset(iris)[subset(s(), curveNumber == 0)$pointNumber + 1,]
       ggplotly(
         ggplot(iris_ind, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
         geom_bar(stat = "identity")
       )
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `updateNavbarPage` after providing your `navbarPage` with an `id`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

# ui with two panes
# when you click on the outlier in the first plot
# you are routed to the second "point explorer" page
ui <- navbarPage("Plotly On Click Switch Pane", id = "navbarID",
                 tabPanel("Page_1",
                          mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot"),
                                    tableOutput("text"))),
                 tabPanel("Page_2",
                          mainPanel(plotlyOutput("ind_plot"))
                 ))


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # plot on first page
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(source = "sub_iris",
             ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width)) +
               geom_boxplot()
    )
  })

  # create reactive for subset plot on second tab
  s <- reactive({
    event_data("plotly_click", source = "sub_iris")
    })

  observeEvent(s(), {
    updateNavbarPage(session, inputId = "navbarID", selected = "Page_2")
  })

  # plot text on first page (test)
  output$text <- renderTable(req(s()))

  # this is the correct plot, but I want to re-route the user here when they click on a point
  output$ind_plot <- renderPlotly({
    req(s())
    iris_ind <- subset(iris)[subset(s(), curveNumber == 0)$pointNumber + 1,]
    ggplotly(
      ggplot(iris_ind, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity")
    )
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```